# How to solve for the 'double opacity' problem during a faze-in animation using psuedo elements

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm attempting to recreate the Chrome tabs in pure CSS. The tricky bit is the inverse border radius at the bottom of the active and hover tabs. I have solved this by giving each `li` for the tab `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements, creating a circle with borders in which the inner circle matched the border radius I needed, setting three of the borders to `transparent` with the fourth one (lined up with the tab) to the tab color. The following is an image demonstrating it (left is the "debug" showing all four borders of the circle, right is the end product)

[image]

This allows me to have a sort of inverse border radius and have the tab "flare out" when connecting to the page. Pretty nice effect.

The problem that I'm having is for the hover effect. What I want to happen: the inactive tabs should have a hover effect where it transitions from the black inactive to a lighter color. I'm using keyframe animations, since apparently psuedo elements don't support `transition` (tho apparently there's conflicting info on this, I couldn't get it to work).

When the animation fires, it technically works, except that the overlap of the `:before,:after` pseudo elements with the base tab doubles up the opacity during the transition.

The image below show what it looks like in the middle of the animation: you will notice that in the lower left and right of the tab, the overlap for the inverse rounded border technique shows up brighter, and makes the animation look janky

[image]

This makes total sense as to why it's happening, but I just don't know how to solve for it. I've   attempted several solutions including setting zindex i various different ways to try to "clip" the border effect with the tab, but I haven't come to a good solution yet.

CodePen for reference. I've tried to comment best I can to make it more accessible. Additionally, the animation loops as I found it easier to visualize without having to hover over it over and over:

https://codepen.io/blitzmann/pen/ZEQvXzQ?editors=1100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways. Firstly, you can use an opaque color instead of transparent. In this case you need to use the background color of the `tab-container` as starting color, i.e. black.

```
@keyframes hover-right {
 0% { 
   border-color : transparent transparent black transparent;
 }
 100% {
   border-color: transparent transparent red transparent
 }
}
```

This solution is simple but may not be reusable in some cases. For example, if you change the background color, you need to change it in the animation too.

Second way is to animate opacity instead of background and border colors. However, this will also change the opacity of the text inside the tab. To overcome this problem you can put an additional element inside the `li` and animate that instead of the whole `li`.